# Polynomial Factorizations

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions, factoring

Find the zeros of this function:

$f(x) = x^2 - 3x - 40.$

My homework tells me to use a graphing calculator but I don't have one. How can I solve this w/o one?

- Thank you everyone for your help. I understand factoring a bit better now :)

Comment: Is it common to use graphic calculators for solving quadratic equations? Since when? Anyway, for solving a quadratic equation there are many ways you could get the solution, completing the square seems to be appropriate.

Comment: I've gotten a few similar problems correct by plugging in random numbers but I don't how to find the zero functions without a graph.    @Hirshy thank you I will try that!

Comment: Well, why teaching a formula to 12-year-old children, when you have graphic calculators?

Comment: If you have access to the Internet, you have a graphing calculator: e.g., https://www.desmos.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
(x-8)(x+5) = x^2-3x-40
$$
because
$$
(x+a)(x+b) = x^2+(a+b)x + ab
$$

Comment: Ah I see I was focusing on graphing when I should have been factoring instead!

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite well known "quadratic formula", that given a polynomial $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, the roots of the polynomial are given by $$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$ 
The roots of the polynomial are the zeros of $f(x)$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes I forgot all about this formula thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$4f(x)=4x^2-12x-160=(2x-3)^2-\text{what?}$

Comment: It's just my opinion, but it took me a couple of seconds to realize that you expected the OP to put a number in place of that "?"...

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thank you. I've changed it. I am hoping OP gets an understanding of the method "completing the square". The multiplication by $4$ (or by $4a$ for $g(x)=ax^2+bc+c$ so that $4ag(x)=4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac=(2ax+b)^2+4ac-b^2$ is something I learned from someone else on this site, and I wish I'd known it earlier. It isn't quite the first thing you think of doing, but it is the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I'm terrible at remembering formulas. If it isn't too much trouble can you list the steps to your problem? Are you factoring it out?